# Errors in function, but the function works - why?

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I have a function that generates a random filename in the format `"greetingXX.gif"` where `"XX"` is a number between 1 and 20.  See code below:

```
 1 function getGIF(callback) {
 2    let randomGIF;
 3    let gifName = "greeting";
 4    const GIF_EXTENSION = ".gif";
 5    const MAX_GREETING = 20;
 6    randomGIF = Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX_GREETING) + 1;
 7    if (randomGIF < 10) {
 8       gifName += "0" + randomGIF;
 9    } else {
10       gifName += randomGIF;
11    }
12    gifName += GIF_EXTENSION;
13    callback(gifName);
14 }
```

The function works, BUT in WebStorm I get the following warnings:

```
Unused Variable randomGIF (Line 2)
Unused constant MAX_GREETING (Line 5)
Element MAX_GREETING is not imported (Line 6)
Variable gifName might not have been initialised (Line 8 and Line 10)
```

Like I say, the function does exactly what it is supposed to do.  But why am I getting these warnings?  And more specifically, how do I change my code so I don't get them?

Comment: For me, no warnings are shown for your code. Please try invalidating caches (**File | Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart**)

Comment: OK that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by invalidating caches (File | Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart).  Thanks to [lena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena) for this!